# Automatically email Outlook calendar?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, automation, calendar

I'm not allowed to sync my work calendar with my home calendar through the usual methods, but I am able to email my calendar to a personal address and then sync to my home calendar.

Is there a way that I can automate this, so that every 7 days Outlook 2010 or 2013 emails my personal address the next 7 days of my calendar?

I've looked for an add-on and can't find one. I'm wondering if I can combine a scheduled email task with some VBA or other method.

Or, maybe there is a plugin out there that I haven't found yet?

Comment: Is it possible to send an automatic email every 7 days, it might be possible with an add-on, but there is no default out of the box feature that supports this.

Comment: Ramhound, thanks, I know how to use automated tasks to send emails. Was wondering if there was an add-on, or a work around that maybe combined automated tasks with something else. Doesn't have to be simple!

Comment: I am not going to start looking for an add-on that does this, you can do that, and I don't do product recomendations here a Superuser.

Comment: Edited the question to make it clearer as to what I'm looking for help with.

Comment: You can always write your own add-on.  Its unlikely you will be able to do this with a VBA script.  Here is a general idea of how you would write a VBA macro that sends an email though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330897/how-to-send-a-mail-automatically found it by doing a `Google` search

Answer (score 1):

I know this an old topic but it is similar to what I was trying to do.  I found the following [Link on Technet](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/12/17/hey-scripting-guy-december-17-2009.aspx) which explains how to schedule a task to run each week.

Comment: I know the linked page contains a LOT of data but a precis or abridged version posted into your answer (giving source) would make it future-proof in case the linked webpage moves and/or someone else want so to do a search for it.